# Can you configure Supervisor + multiple Daphne processes w/ ssl endpoints

Tags: python, django, ssl, supervisord, daphne

I'm trying to configure the following setup:

- Django w/ channels
- Multiple Daphne processes as the ASGI server, with ssl endpoints
- Supervisor managing Daphne
- No other server (nginx, etc.) in front of Daphne

Without using ssl, I can bind all the Daphne processes to a single file descriptor and Supervisor will expose this as single endpoint.

This doesn't seem possible when using ssl endpoints unless I'm missing something.

My supervisord.conf looks like this:

```
[fcgi-program:daphne]
command=/usr/local/bin/daphne
    -e ssl:port=8443:privateKey=/project/ssl/key.pem:certKey=/project/ssl/cert.pem
    -u /tmp/daphne%(process_num)d.sock
    --fd 0
    myapp.asgi:application
directory=/project/src
numprocs=4
process_name=daphne%(process_num)d
socket=tcp://0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I bring up the server, however, it only listens to the first process, and I get this error for each of the n-1 additional processes that are spawned:

```
DEBG 'daphne1' stderr output:
INFO     HTTPFactory starting on 8000
INFO     Starting factory <daphne.http_protocol.HTTPFactory object at 0xffffa448db40>
INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
INFO     Configuring endpoint ssl:port=8443:certKey=/project/ssl/cert.pem:privateKey=/project/ssl/key.pem
CRITICAL Listen failure: Couldn't listen on any:8443: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne1.sock
INFO     HTTPFactory starting on '/run/daphne1.sock'
```

So basically, the processes start fine, but Daphne is itself grabbing the first tcp socket at 8443, and then nothing else can bind to it.

Is there anyway around this without running Daphne w/o ssl and putting a proxy server (nginx) in front of Supervisor to handle the ssl connection?